# collapse 2-col data frame where col1 contains names, col2 contains values

Tags: r, tidyverse

I think there must be an easy way to collapse the input table to yield the desired output table, but I'm blanking on it.

```
library(tidyverse)
input <- tribble(
  ~name, ~value,
  "animal", "pig",
  "animal", "dog",
  "animal", "cat",
  "plant", "tree",
  "plant", "bush",
  "plant", "flower"
)

output <- tribble(
  ~animal, ~plant,
  "pig", "tree",
  "dog", "bush",
  "cat", "flower"
)
```

In `input`, col1 contains the variable label for each value in col2. In `output`, the table is reformatted so that the values in `input$value` appear in columns named according to the corresponding elements in `input$name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `unstack` from `base R` (no packages used)

```
unstack(input, value ~ name)
#   animal  plant
#1    pig   tree
#2    dog   bush
#3    cat flower
```

---

Or with `dcast` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(input, rowid(name)~ name)[,-1]
#    animal  plant
#1    pig   tree
#2    dog   bush
#3    cat flower
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
input %>% 
    group_split(name, keep = FALSE) %>% 
    bind_cols
```

Or using `split`

```
split(input$value, input$name) %>% 
         bind_cols
```

---

Or another option with `spread`

```
library(tidyr)
input %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(name)) %>% 
   spread(name, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can create a `row_number()` for every `name` and then `spread`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

input %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(name, value) %>%
  select(-row)

#   animal plant 
#  <chr>  <chr> 
#1  pig    tree  
#2  dog    bush  
#3  cat    flower
```